# xsl transformer in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, transformation

I have problems to find a good Javascript library to transform XML (in this case, XSD) to XML by XSL. I found some Javascript libraries online, but none of them is working.. I tried to transform it online (by 'http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html'), and that actually works! But when I use a Javascript library, it does not work unfortunately.. What am I doing wrong here?

This is code I have now:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="output"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.xslt.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#output').xslt({xmlUrl: 'notworking.xsd', xslUrl: 'notworking.xsl'});
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the 'notworking.xsd' file:

```
<xs:import schemaLocation="https://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd" namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"/>

<xs:element name="list">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="list.start" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

the 'notworking.xsl' file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="xs:schema">
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="fn:distinct-values(.//xs:element/@name)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="schema" select="."/>
        <xsl:element name="xsd">
            <xsl:for-each select=".//xs:element[@name]">
                <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xs:element">
        <xsl:variable name="type" select="fn:tokenize(@type,':')[last()]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="base" select="fn:tokenize(ancestor::xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name=$type]/xs:complexContent/xs:extension/@base,':')[last()]"/>
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@minOccurs"/>
            <xsl:variable name="sequence" select="./xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element|ancestor::xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name=$type]//xs:extension/xs:sequence/xs:element"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space() ne ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it doesn't work"? What is the error? Can you create a code snippet or plunker showing the error?

Comment: There are xsl engines in most browsers (FF and MSIE at least) I think, no need for extra javascript or call somewhere

Comment: That is an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet while browsers are only supporting XSLT 1.0 so you will need to look into Saxon-CE or Saxon-JS if you want to run XSLT 2.0 in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Your stylesheet requires XSLT 2.0 support (for example, the distinct-values() function does not exist in XSLT 1.0).

The XSLT processors supplied by the major browser vendors only support XSLT 1.0.

Give Saxon-JS a try: it supports XSLT 3.0. See http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml (if you can read the documentation, then you are already running Saxon-JS successfully in your browser).